# Odd Function Integral?

Tags: integration

I know if $f$ is an odd function then

$$\int_{-L}^L f(x)\:dx = 0$$

my question is, is the converse necessarily true? Intuitively, I feel it should be that by assuming that the integral with those symmetric bounds is zero I can somehow show $f(-x) = -f(x)$, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

My attempt:

$$\int_{-L}^L f(x)\:dx = \int_{-L}^{0} f(x) \: dx + \int_{0}^{L} f(x) \: dx = 0$$.

So,

$$\int_{-L}^{0} f(x) \: dx = - \int_{0}^{L} f(x) \: dx$$

How do I use this to show $f(-x) = -f(x)$, or am I wrong to think the converse is necessarily true?

Can I just do this from my last step,

$$\int_{0}^{L} f(-x) \: dx = - \int_{0}^{L} f(x) \: dx$$.

Thus $f(-x) = -f(x)$, or is this not allowed?

Comment: For a continous function, when you make the interval of integration very short, the value of the integral approaches the value of the function times the length of the interval. Subtract everything except a short interval from the last equality you have.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus lets you differentiate both sides with respect to $L$.

Comment: If $\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx=0$ for *all* $L>0$, then $f$ is an odd function.

Comment: Suppose L = 1, and we know it holds true for that case, then can we conclude $f$ is odd on the interval $[-1,1]$? This is essentially what I am taking for granted for a problem I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, suppose that $L$ is fixed. Without losing generality, we can take $L=1$.

Then just take $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\in [-1,0],\\1-4x,&x\in[0,1].\end{cases}$$ Obviously, $\int_{-1}^1f(x)dx=0$, yet $f$ is not odd.

Second, if we put the condition that $\int_{-L}^Lf(x)dx=0$ *for every* $L>0$, the situation changes. Suppose for simplicity that $f$ is continuous, then the antiderivative $F:x\to\int_{0}^xf(s)ds$ is a $C^1$ function.

We can say that $$\int_{-L}^Lf(x)dx=0\Rightarrow  \forall L>0\ \ F(L)-F(-L)=0,$$hence the derivative with respect to $L$ is also zero:$$\forall L>0\ \ F'(L)+F'(-L)=0\Rightarrow \forall L>0\ \ f(L)+f(-L)=0,$$therefore $f$ is odd.

Comment: Thanks that counterexample shows it's not sufficient to conclude $f$ is odd on $[-L,L]$ from just a single $L$. Looks like I have to rethink how to do my original problem...

Comment: @Eddie You are welcome!